MySQL previously successful query has stopped working - Can't write; duplicate key in table '/tmp/#sql2e02_11_6'
I have a large table (~292GB), and some queries that used to work have stopped working. The error is:
Reason: SQL Error [1022] [23000]: Can't write; duplicate key in table '/tmp/#sql2e02_11_10'
What I've tried and did not work.

check space on disk , there are more than 250gb free
set big_tables to 1
increase max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size

I'm running out of ideas.
@set asin = 'B0XXXXXXXX' 
@set dateAt = '2024-01-31'
SELECT TRUNCATE(avg(dr.`rankV`),0) rankKey, t.sterm, TRUNCATE(avg(t.asinRank),1) asinRank, truncate(avg(t.cc),0) cc,
(SELECT TRUNCATE(100*marketShare,0) from (
SELECT a.name,avg(ar.asinRank) asinRank, count(*) cc, count(*)/sum(count(*)) over () AS marketShare
                     FROM US_daily_asin_keywords ar
                     INNER JOIN US_asins a ON a.id = ar.`asinId`
                     INNER JOIN US_keywords k ON k.id = ar.`keywordId`
                     INNER JOIN reports r ON r.id = ar.reportId 
                     WHERE k.sterm = t.sterm AND r.endDay>:dateAt
                     GROUP BY a.name
                     ORDER BY cc DESC) t1
WHERE t1.name = :asin) marketShare
FROM US_daily_ranks dr
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT keywordId, k.sterm, TRUNCATE(avg(asinRank),1) asinRank, count(*) cc FROM US_daily_asin_keywords ar
    INNER JOIN US_keywords k ON k.id = ar.`keywordId` 
    INNER JOIN reports r on r.id = ar.reportId  
    inner join US_asins ua on ua.id = ar.asinId 
    WHERE ua.name = :asin
    AND r.endDay > :dateAt
    GROUP by ar.keywordId
    ORDER BY cc desc ) t ON t.keywordId = dr.keywordId
GROUP BY t.sterm
ORDER by cc DESC;


Please provide some code, as in [mre], not just an error message.

While you have enough diskspace, a temporary file created on the /tmp might make that filesystem run out of space. Is /tmp a different filesystem ?

You might have better luck on https://dba.stackexchange.com
